# Launching an activity in the application by long pressing a key

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android that requires the launch of an activity by long pressing a key on the phone for instance a search button, which then excecutes in the background.
i would like to know how this can be done effectively or any other alternative methods,Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in the foreground, you are welcome to watch for a long press on some key and try to respond to it.

If your app is not in the foreground, you cannot find out about long-presses on any key. The only user input that background code can respond to are presses of the `CAMERA` button or a `MEDIA` button on a headset, where these exist.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would you please show me how to do it when the application is on the foreground.?

Comment: @PtaRz: Override `onKeyDown()` and watch for relevant `KeyEvent`s, specifically ones containing, `FLAG_LONG_PRESS`, I imagine.